# appsettings in .net core sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

I have a problem when trying to connect to the database in SQL Server to make a Web Api in .net core.

This is my code:

appsettings.json

```
 {
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    " "DefaultConnection": "Server=ipserver,portserver;Database=Equipamiento;user id=userserver;password=password;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"


  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

Controller/TipoEquipoMasterAPI.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
namespace VeranderAngularCore.Data
{
    public class TipoEquipoMaster
    {
        [Key]
        public int IDTipoEquipo { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name ="TipoEquipo")]
        public string TipoEquipo { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Estado")]
        public int _Status { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Data/TipoEquipoMaster.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
namespace VeranderAngularCore.Data
{
    public class TipoEquipoContext:DbContext
    {
        public TipoEquipoContext(DbContextOptions<TipoEquipoContext> options) : base(options) { }

        public TipoEquipoContext() { }

        public DbSet<TipoEquipoMaster> TipoEquipoMaster { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Data/TipoEquipoContext.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
namespace VeranderAngularCore.Data
{
    public class TipoEquipoContext:DbContext
    {
        public TipoEquipoContext(DbContextOptions<TipoEquipoContext> options) : base(options) { }

        public TipoEquipoContext() { }

        public DbSet<TipoEquipoMaster> TipoEquipoMaster { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller/TipoEquipoMasterAPI.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using VeranderAngularCore.Data;

// For more information on enabling Web API for empty projects, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860

namespace VeranderAngularCore.Controllers
{
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/TipoEquipoMasterAPI")]
    public class TipoEquipoMasterAPI : Controller
    {


        private readonly TipoEquipoContext _context;

        public TipoEquipoMasterAPI(TipoEquipoContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/values

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("TipoEquipo")]
        public IEnumerable<TipoEquipoMaster> GetStudentMasters()
        {
            return _context.TipoEquipoMaster;

        }

    }
}
```

And when trying to enter:http://localhost:14621/api/TipoEquipoMasterAPI/TipoEquipo 
I get the following error: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Comment: Theres an extra " " " in at your connection string. Try correct that, however the ERR_CONNECTION_RESET could hint network issues

Comment: Copy the code wrong, I have it:      "DefaultConnection": "Server=ipserver,portserver;Database=Equipamiento;user id=userserver;password=password;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"

Comment: Can post the startup.cs code?

Answer (score 0):

Hi did you add the service for DbContext?

in Startup.cs ConfigureServices method try to add

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
         services.AddDbContext<TipoEquipoContext>(options =>
         options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    }
```

I'm not sure if you already have this... hmmmmm...

Answer (score 0):

If you have any many-to-many relationships, you might have a problem with a loop in your object graph as EFCore does not support lazy loading at this time.

If so, you can configure your serializer to not follow graph loops.

In your Startup.cs file, replace the `services.AddMvc()` line with this:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
```